# Unable to produce `0 to 9` and `A to Z` by turns

Tags: excel, vba

I've written a script in vba which is able to produce letters from ***A to Z***. Now, I wish to produce `A-Z` and `0-9` by turns. I'm not sure but I think ***Like*** operator has something to do with it.

I've tried with (producing alphabets):

```
Sub GetAlphabets()
    Dim I&

    For I = 65 To 90
        Debug.Print Chr(I)
    Next I
End Sub
```

***My question - is there any way I can produce `0 to 9` and `A to Z` by turns?***

Expected output:

```
A
B
C
D
.
.
.
.
0
1
2
3
4
.
.
```

***EDIT:***

This is the very reason why I went for the solution (easy to implement) provided by @Tom:

```
Sub FetchLinks()
    Const URL$ = "https://www.sharedividends.com.au/wp-content/custom/livesearch.php?"
    Dim params$, I&, N$

    For I = 0 To 35
        N = IIf(I <= 25, Chr(I + 65), CStr(I - 26))

        params = "q=" & N

        Debug.Print URL & params
    Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not create an array with 36 items? Also, why do you think that the Like operator is relevant?

Comment: What do you mean "at the same time"?

Comment: Without creating multiple loops @SJR.

Comment: If you are still unclear, let me know @SJR.

Comment: @robots.txt see my answer (edited). But there is no benefit using one loop instead of 2. The amount of iteration steps is the same if you do `0…35` or `0…25 + 0…9`

Comment: Because I thought `Like` operator works more or less how regex works, as in "[A-Z0-9]" @John Coleman.

Comment: @robots.txt - FYI posted a flexibilized array approach

Comment: Please check out the edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like the following

```
Sub GetAlphabets()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To 35
        Debug.Print IIf(i <= 25, Chr(i + 65), CStr(i - 26))
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I wish to get.The only problem is - the numbers have leading spaces. Can you strip that space? Thanks.

Comment: @robots.txt That's just how they're displayed in the `Debug.Print` statement. They won't as a variable. I think the only way you can get around this is by converting it to a `String` (see update)

Comment: Actually there is no benefit in using one loop over 2 loops. The amount of iterations is the same and it is much less readable than 2 loops. I would recommend to use 2 loops instead for better maintenance, better readability and same performance.

Comment: This is so perfect!!!!!!! I finally need them as strings as I will use them in a paginated website links. Thanks.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I agree with you in this instance but may be beneficial if it is part of a larger code (which by the sounds of it, it is)

Answer (score 4):

Something like that?

```
Sub GetAlphabets()
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 0 To 25
        Debug.Print Chr(i + 65), IIf(i < 10, i, "-")
    Next i
End Sub
```

Outputs both in only one loop:

```
A              0 
B              1 
C              2 
D              3 
E              4 
F              5 
G              6 
H              7 
I              8 
J              9 
K             -
L             -
M             -
N             -
O             -
P             -
Q             -
R             -
S             -
T             -
U             -
V             -
W             -
X             -
Y             -
Z             -
```

---

Alternative

```
Sub GetAlphabetsAndNumbers()
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 0 To 35
        If i < 26 Then
            Debug.Print Chr(i + 65)
        Else
            Debug.Print i - 26
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

But it should be the same speed than using 2 loops

```
Sub GetAlphabets()
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 0 To 25
        Debug.Print Chr(i + 65)
    Next i

    For i = 0 To 9
        Debug.Print i
    Next i
End Sub
```

That outputs

```
A
B
C
…
X
Y
Z
 0 
 1 
 2 
 3 
 4 
 5 
 6 
 7 
 8 
 9
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need it exactly with that output (letters and then numbers) you could use:

```
Sub GetAlphabets()
Dim i As Byte

For i = 65 To 90
    Debug.Print Chr(i)
Next i

For i = 48 To 57
    Debug.Print Chr(i)
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**Flexible array output**

For the sake of the art I demonstrate a flexibilized approach allowing a **reduced number** of characters and numbers:

**Example call**

```
Sub Test()
  ' Example a) calls the helper function without parameters defaulting to A-Z and 0-9
    Debug.Print Join(GetAlphaAndNums(), ",")      ' ~> A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
  ' Example b) calls only 10 characters and 5 digits
    Debug.Print Join(GetAlphaAndNums(10, 5), ",") ' ~> A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,0,1,2,3,4
  ' or
    Dim v: v = GetAlphaAndNums(10, 5)
    Debug.Print Join(v, ",")
End Sub
```

**Function GetAlphaAndNums**

```
Function GetAlphaAndNums(Optional ByVal alphaLength& = 26, Optional ByVal numLength& = 10) As Variant()
    Dim chars, i&
  ' [1] get ASC values of alphabet
    If alphaLength > 0 Then
        If alphaLength > 26 Then alphaLength = 26            ' allow alphabetic characters from A-Z only

        chars = Evaluate("column(1:" & alphaLength & ")+64") ' assign alphabetic asc values to 1-based array chars

    Else                                                     ' (i.e. no alphabetic characters at all)
        If numLength = 0 Then numLength = 1                  '  avoid empty array
        ReDim chars(1 To Abs(numLength))                     '  define any array length if no alphabetic chars at al
    End If
    ReDim Preserve chars(1 To alphaLength + numLength)       ' provide for sufficient items
  ' [2] Fill array with characters and numbers
    For i = 1 To UBound(chars)
        chars(i) = IIf(i <= alphaLength, Chr(chars(i)), CStr(i - alphaLength - 1))
    Next i
    GetAlphaAndNums = chars                                  ' return array
End Function
```